# Laravel: custom logging message

Tags: laravel-4, monolog

I am getting `2014-06-23 02:23:14] log.INFO: General information log [] []` in my `log.txt` while calling `$monolog->info('General information log');` I don't understand the need of `[] []` hence I want to get rid of these square brackets from logged message. But I don't have any idea how...!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I did this via code hack

1st:

> E:\xampp\htdocs\my_site\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter.php

2nd: Find this line

```
const SIMPLE_FORMAT = "[%datetime%] %channel%.%level_name%: %message% %context% %extra%\n";
```

3rd: and replace

```
const SIMPLE_FORMAT = "[%datetime%] %channel%.%level_name%: %message% \n";
```

> [2014-06-23 13:23:33] production.INFO: yada ya da error

This is my log file

It will remove the square brackets I have tested.